# GPS error value on eclipse

Tags: gps

I am working on project that get the longitude and latitude and it is everywhere, but I need to get the error estimation at least to draw a circle around my GPS point. How i can find this error in eclipse.

It is known that the total Potential error is around 15 m and the total Typical error is around 10 m. Do i need the average deviation to find the error?

I just need to know how to find the accuracy of my GPS and what values can i fetch using Eclipse?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your "eclipse" As far as GPS error, there are some things to consider...

Some receivers can output a NMEA GST message with includes error estimates.

You can watch GDOP and HDOP values to get an idea as well as number of satellites tracked.

Assuming a GDOP < 6 and an HDOP <3 with more then 4 tracked satellites you should achieve the receivers specified RMS accuracy.

Another, more complicated method, which should be the basis for the results in then mentioned GST message is Range Residuals. Advanced receivers may output these RRE measurements for each satellite. Using this information you can even detect errors such as multipath, and RF interference. RRE values tell how well a satellites range measurements match the resolved position result.